# AWS Serverless Lambda Java retrieve all items from Amazon DynamoDB without variable types

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I have written a lambda function that scans all items in dynamoDB but it retrieves them with its types. How can I remove them? Should I try to parse data in an appropriate way for me or there is a better way of doing it?

```
public class Get implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {
    AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
            .withTableName("xxx");

    static final int STATUS_CODE_NO_CONTENT = 204;
    static final int STATUS_CODE_CREATED = 201;
    static final int STATUS_CODE_FAILED = 400;
    @Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent request, Context context) {
        Map<String, String> map = request.getPathParameters();
        ContactDetails contactDetails = null;
        APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent response = null;
        int code = STATUS_CODE_NO_CONTENT;
        try {
            ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);
            code = STATUS_CODE_CREATED;
            response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().withStatusCode(code).withIsBase64Encoded(Boolean.FALSE).withHeaders(Collections.emptyMap()).withBody(new Gson().toJson(result.getItems()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            code = STATUS_CODE_FAILED;
            response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().withStatusCode(code).withIsBase64Encoded(Boolean.FALSE).withHeaders(Collections.emptyMap()).withBody(e.toString());
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

response: [{"kontent":{"s":"ys"},"id":{"s":"ys"}},{"id":{"s":"asdassa"}}]
need to make it
[{"id":"ys", "kontent": "ys"}, {"id":"asdassa"}]

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwrap the `AttributeValue` instances that are returned from `result.getItems()`. Simple for a string, but there are more complex data types too.

Implement this method, then wrap `result.getItems()` with it, i.e. `convertItems(result.getItems())`

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> convertItems(List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> items) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> newItems = new ArrayList<>(items.size());
    for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : items) { 
        Map<String, Object> newItem = new HashMap<>();
        item.forEach((key, value) -> {
            switch(value.type()) {
                case S:
                    newItem.put(key, value.s());
                    break;
                // Any other types you want to support besides string
            }
        });
        newItems.add(newItem);
    }
    return newItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is definetly a better way of performing **Amazon DynamoDB** CRUD operations from within an AWS Lambda functions.

Move away from **AWS SDK for Java V1** to **V2**. Amazon Strongly encourages devs to use V2 when using the JAVA SDK and the Enhanced Client to perform Amazon DynamoDB CRUD operations.

[software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbEnhancedClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/DynamoDbEnhancedClient.html)

For details, see:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/dynamodb-enhanced-client.html

This client works nicely witin an AWS Lambda function. For details on how to use this client witin an AWS Lambda Function that uses the Java run-time Lambda API, see this article:

[Creating an AWS Lambda function that detects images with Personal Protective Equipment](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_ppe)

This example creates a Java Lambda function that detects PPE information in the image using the Amazon Rekognition service and creates a record in an Amazon DynamoDB table. This shows you best practice to perform CRUD operations from wihtin a Lambda fuction using the **Enhanced Client**.

**UPDATE**

When you use the Enchanced Client and a **Scan** operation, the **Scan** method returns **Java Objects**. You do NOT HAVE TO use logic like you do with **V1** and **getItems**. That is one of the best parts of using this client.

To get the data, you simply call the method that belongs to the Java object. For example, here is a Scan method returning **Customer** objects, To get the data, you simply call methods that belong to a **Customer** object - for example, **getCustName()**:

```
public static void scan( DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient) {
        try{
            DynamoDbTable<Customer> custTable = enhancedClient.table("Customer", TableSchema.fromBean(Customer.class));
            Iterator<Customer> results = custTable.scan().items().iterator();
            while (results.hasNext()) {
                Customer rec = results.next();
                System.out.println("The record id is "+rec.getId());
                System.out.println("The name is " +rec.getCustName());
            }

        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
```

Comment: cool, for now need to just get these items to check if it works properly but surely would need improvement in code later on, thanks for suggestion!

Comment: I will update my answer.

Comment: OP doesn't necessarily have a `Customer` class to map to. What if he wants to dump the entire table *without* knowing the schema? What if he wants to do it in a way that will expose additional properties in the JSON without recompiling and redeploying?